# what are the real meaning of exact differential form and closed differential form?

Tags: differential-geometry

I know that a differential k-form $\omega$ on $U$ is closed if $d\omega=0$, and that is exact so there is a (k-1)-form $\tau$ on $U$ that $\omega=d\tau$. But I don't know real meaning of these concepts. Are they have geometrical concepts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, a differential $k$-form represents infinitesimal oriented $k$-volume (volume is $k$ dimensions) with a prescribed density (the function in front of the basis elements). If the differential of that form (which is a $k-1$-form) is zero, then that means that the density of the given form does not vary as your location on $M$ changes. Or in otherwords, the density is constant across $M$. An exact form is simply one which has an antiderivative (where derivative means *exterior* derivative), which allows for iterated integration via the Generalized Stokes' Theorem.